# Synchronization of property access with Class Lock

Tags: c#, .net, properties, synchronization, locking

Please consider the following code

```
public class DataModel
{
    public int a { get; set; }
}

public static class StaticAccess
{
    private static _Data = new DataModel();

    private static DataModel Data {
        lock(_Data) {
            return _Data;
        }
    }    
}
```

Will an access to property `a` such us `StaticAccess.Data.a = 3;` will lock for the entire property value assignment or just for the `_Data` static field reference retrieval?

In other words, can I use the above implementation to synchronize the access to the properties of the underlying data model or do I have to implement the lock in every single property of it?
e.g.

```
public class DataModel
{
    private int _a;
    public int a {
    get {
        lock(this) {
            return _a;
        }
    }
    set {
        lock(this) {
            _a = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your first example will synchronize access to *the instance of `DataModel`* in the `StaticAccess` class (i.e.: to the `_Data` field), *not* to members of the instance of `DataModel` itself. For that you need your second example.

Side note: Avoid locking on `this`, and use a dedicated object to lock on, as you don't know who else might lock on the instance. Use something like

```
public class DataModel
{
    private readonly object _lock= new object();
    private int _a;
    public int a {
    get {
        lock(_lock) {
            return _a;
        }
    }
    set {
        lock(_lock) {
            _a = value;
        }
    }
}
```

***Edit based on comments:***

The `Data` property of `StaticAccess` returns the instance of `DataModel`. So only thread at a time can obtain the reference to that instance. The goal, however, is to synchronize access to `DataModel.a`. Since access to `DataModel.a` is not synchronized any code that tries to either read or write to `DataModel.a` is not synchronized meaning that multiple threads accessing `StaticAccess.Data.a` is not synchronized:

```
void ThreadProc1()
{
   // (might) block on "get StaticAccess.Data"
   // will not block on "DataModel.a = 20"
   StaticAccess.Data.a = 20;
}

void ThreadProc2()
{
    // (might) block on "StaticAccess.Data"
    // will not block on "DataModel.a = 10"
    StaticAccess.Data.a = 10;
    // (might) block on "StaticAccess.Data"
    // will not block on "DataModel.a"
    // "StaticAccess.Data.a" might be 10 or 20;
    Console.WriteLine(StaticAccess.Data.a);
}
```

Comment: Sure thing, locked on this for brevity's sake. Thank you!

Comment: P.S.
But since in my scenario `_Data` can only be accessed via static `StaticAccess.Data` property, which would be locking on _Data, wouldn't that mean locking on ANYTHING inside `DataModel _Data`?
Please consider that I'm not intersted in generally locking on `DataModel` properties, but only the ones I access via `StaticAccess.Data`

Comment: *IF* the instance isn't shared, and *ONLY* accessible from within StaticAccess, then it would work. But since you return the instance in the property getter in your example, other code in other threads might get and hold on to a reference of that instance and modify it, which renders it not threadsafe. So only one thread at a time can obtain a reference to _Data, but multiple threads might change the contents of _Data at any time.

Comment: Ok! What if I'm not planning on saving a reference to the `_Data` field anywhere else than in `StaticAccess` and access that field only through it, would it be viable then?

Comment: I should've said "get and use a reference to that instance" instead of "get and hold on to a reference of that instance", the following code 
Thread1: DataModel dm1 = StaticAccess.Data; dm1.a = 20; 
Thread2: DataModel dm2 = StaticAccess.Data; dm2.a = 30;
is already not threadsafe. Your only options are to implement synchronization in the DataModel class self, or to not return an instance of the DataModel instance that is supposed to be synchronized (and, for example, provide synchronized access in the StaticAccess class to properties of the DataModel instance).

Comment: Yes, I already understood it as "get and use a reference to that instance", for this my question: What If I'm never using a reference to the _Data field and access it ONLY and ALWAYS via StaticAccess?
In my scenario, for example, I would be never doing `DataModel dm1 = StaticAccess.Data`.
I am REALLY only interseted in accessing props like `StaticAccess.Data.[prop]`

Comment: But surely you'll use StaticAnswer.Data in one way or another, either by reading or by writing to it. I'll update the answer with an edit explaining the scenario

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70697/discussion-between-shockwaver-and-willem-van-rumpt).